# "tile_dimensions" error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: java, gis, google-earth, google-earth-engine, geography

I'm trying to export the images in [TFRecords format](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7cced1b1ad573a3b1d43002a57e05649) in Google Earth Engine and I got the "**tile_dimensions must be specified for TfRecord export**" error:

Here is the code:

```
var Regoin= imageCollection.filterBounds(geometry);
var image= Regoin.filter(ee.Filter.date('2015-01-01','2021-01-01'))
print(image.size())


Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image,
  description: "Chicago_Images",
  folder: 'GEE',
  fileNamePrefix:'Chicago_Images_2',
  region: geometry,
  scale:30,
  maxPixels: 50000000,
  shardSize: 100,
  fileDimensions:5000,
  fileFormat: 'TFRecord',

});
```

How can I identify tiles?
I would appreciate your helping me solve the error.